# Port Forwarding on macOS Monterey

Tags: pfctl

I've switched to macOS Monterey and am not able to get port forwarding working for localhost (http and https) using the loopback interface lo0. I'm using pf and doing exactly what I was doing before the OS upgrade but without success:

Basically, I create a pf anchors file: /etc/pf.anchors/myorganization

```
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 7000
```

Add a reference to it in `/etc/pf.conf`:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "myorganization/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
load anchor "myorganization" from "/etc/pf.anchors/myorganization"
```

I test the anchors:

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/myorganization
```

and the result looks good:

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 7000
```

I've enabled them:

```
sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf
sudo pfctl -e
```

I've added localhost to my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

But when I browse to https://localhost I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. If I browse to https://localhost:7000 the site is working fine.

Looking at the tcp traffic using tcpdump, I was expecting to see `> 127.0.0.1.7000` but it shows `> 127.0.0.1.443`:

```
23:48:04.130611 IP6 (flowlabel 0xb0300, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 44) ::1.50441 > ::1.443: Flags [S], seq 3067776972, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 964644834 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:48:04.130738 IP6 (flowlabel 0xa0500, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 44) ::1.50442 > ::1.443: Flags [S], seq 3324498656, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 99035196 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:48:04.130869 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    127.0.0.1.50443 > 127.0.0.1.443: Flags [S], seq 3800502092, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2889641981 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:48:04.131018 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    127.0.0.1.50444 > 127.0.0.1.443: Flags [S], seq 2687597757, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3887445210 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:48:04.133055 IP6 (flowlabel 0xf0f00, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 44) ::1.50445 > ::1.443: Flags [S], seq 3046833283, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2977518404 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:48:04.133214 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    127.0.0.1.50446 > 127.0.0.1.443: Flags [S], seq 3143600809, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 4289031031 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Comment: I'm doing something very similar - same process that used to work is not working any longer. :( I don't have an answer, but share your pain.

Comment: Ditto. The same thing happened to me. pf working before Monterrey, now not working with Monterey.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also trying to apply rdr rules on macOS Monterey. Interestingly, while I cannot get rdr rules on `en0` to work, rules on `lo0` (including the exact rule you posted above) work just fine.

Re tcpdump: don't expect to see the port you are forwarding to show up that way. Even the lo0 rule that does work for me shows up in wireshark with the original destination port as if it weren't being forwarded (even while it is in fact being forwarded).

If you want to see the pf logs, try `sudo ifconfig pflog0 create` and then `sudo tcpdump -v -n -e -ttt -i pflog0`. There, if it's working, it should show you something like

```
00:00:00.000000 rule 3/0(match): rdr in on lo0: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64, bad cksum 0 (->3cb6)!)
    127.0.0.1.64597 > 127.0.0.1.3000: Flags [S], cksum 0xf2cc (incorrect -> 0xb902), seq 1023544220, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale6,nop,nop,TS val 1448517328 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

I realize this isn't actually an answer, but it won't let me leave a comment...

Answer (score 0):

I've developed an App for port forwarding on macOS. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/hronro/iPortForwarder

It allows you to easily forward a single port or a range of ports without modifying the system firewall.

[image: scrrenshot]

Comment: Some instructions on how to use it might help here, the UI is rather minimal. Also, does this run `pfctl` in the background to set the forwarding?

Comment: This application does not use `pfctl` at the underlying level, so if you absolutely need to use pf, this application may not be of much help.

Comment: Ah, it does forwarding on application level?

Comment: Yes, it does forward at the application level.